# Overridable colors with defaults in custom SwiftUI component

Tags: ios, swiftui, colors, components

I am currently building some custom components for my SwiftUI app, and wondering how to handle default but overridable UI values, such as colors or paddings, in these components. Let's take a simple example:

```
struct TagView: View {
    let text: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.footnote)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(10.0)
            .background(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(4)
    }
}
```

I would like this element to have a default background color, but to be able to override this from the outside using`.background()`. Unfortunately, it seems that as soon as I use `.background()` inside my component, any attempt to override it from the outside does nothing.

How to handle these sorts of customizations? It seems the native SwiftUI components are able to do this (for example Text() has a default foregroundColor, but you can override it).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo of possible approach - define own `background` modifier with redefined internal default color.

Tested with Xcode 13.2 / iOS 15.2

```
struct TagView: View {
    let text: String

    private var backColor = Color.gray    // << default !!
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.footnote)
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding(10.0)
            .background(backColor)     // << here !!
            .cornerRadius(4)
    }

//  If needed to have own Type for chain of custom modifiers return Self
//  func background(_ color: Color) -> Self {   
    func background(_ color: Color) -> some View {   // << here !!
        var view = self
        view.backColor = color
        return view
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will consider this approach. Nonetheless, it still seems strange to me that for something this basic we have to basically re-implement one of the most basic view modifiers of SwiftUI. I can't imagine this is really an intended way to solve this by Apple. I am also wondering how the native SwiftUI components handle this, since they behave exactly as you would expect them to in this regard.